# In Open ID Connect, why is the id token a JWT token whereas the access token is not?

Tags: openid-connect

I know that the access token can be of any format(it is up to the authorization server), but I noticed that most of the times the access token is not a JWT whereas the id token is a JWT. Why is that so? If it is to check the authenticity of id token over non-ssl connections, wouldn't the same be needed on the access tokens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `id_token` contains the claims ("iss","sub","aud","nonce",...) and is a JWT, **as per the OIDC Specification** : https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse

Access tokens are used as bearer tokens, therefore, the format **is not mandated by the OIDC** specification.

Comment: I can understand why a typical JWT token used for authentication needs to be a JWT token. Server will be needing the signature part to verify "who" is accessing it.

But, with openid, I was under assumption that the id token is merely to just let the authorization server send the user information(or claims) to the client. In SAML, which is redirect based, the signature part is necessary, this is what lets the clients ensure the data they got is indeed from the provider. But that is not needed for openid as it relies on POST requests to get the tokens.

Comment: so, this makes me question why would an id token be a JWT. If it is just to have a standard structure, can we say that the signature part of the JWT is redundant in openid? Or, are the id tokens not just for sending the user informations(claims), but they can be consumed in the resource server APIs too? if so, it makes sense to have the signature part for the id token.

Comment: You need to look at this from the historical perspective. OpenID Connect is built upon OAuth2 framework, so it can use all the flows from OAuth2 (authorization_code, implicit, etc). For example in implicit flow, the id token is send via redirection, so you have the same scenario like with SAML.
Look also from client perspective. Yes, ID token is sending claims about the user, but still this is through network, and this can be malformed. Signature is to ensure authentication and integrity of token (validate if it was not malformed).